# How to update excel spreadsheet embedded in MS Word 2003 using Java

Tags: apache-poi

I have to update a word document which comes with the excel spreadsheet embedded in it in form of a editable table. I have to update this table using Java in a programatic way to replace the values in the excel sheet embedded in document. I looked into all possible options of Apache POI (HWPFDocument methods) to get the handle for the excel spreadsheet object, but so far did not find any method option that can give me control on this object.

Comment: This should help: http://poi.apache.org/poifs/embeded.html

Comment: Usually OLE embedding (e.g. HSSF inside HWPF) is more complicated than OOXML embedding. Could you switch to XWPF ... and modify the included (.docx is a zip file) .xlsx? It could be, that it is not a complete .xlsx , but some kind of calculation xml

Comment: Thanks JensS. I have visited the poi link earlier but not of help from my problem standpoint. I have not come across any method / step which can help me pull the spreadsheet from document

Comment: I've to deal with the .doc file and not .docx, hence not sure if XWPF will support the .doc format.

Comment: XWPF is for OOXML-based documents - so no, XWPF doesn't support OLE/BIFF-based documents like .doc. I haven't spent time to check how the embeddings work with HWPF, but as our embedding page suggest, you would need to handle the entries/subdirectories of the ObjectPool directory via POIFSFileSystem, i.e. there's no API yet to do it for you. If you eventually have a DocumentInputStream to read from, be aware that it much likely isn't a standalone excel sheet and hence can't be parsed by HSSF.

Comment: Thanks kiwiwings

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue i was looking for along time , but i did not find clear answer how we can update the embedded excel file into a word file , after trying many solutions i found a way to update or copy data into the excel embedded file using POI, maybe its  late ,but i hope it will help other people that facing the same problem. the code example below based on the code in  [this link here](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/examples/UpdateEmbeddedDoc.java)

in this example we have a word document ( Microsoft Office 2007 and above) that it has two embedded excel files and we will update both of them each one with different content (data),

you could try to modify this code to support word 2003

```
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JException;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class UpdateEmbeddedDoc {

    private XWPFDocument doc;
    private File docFile;

    private static final String BINARY_EXTENSION = "xls";
    private static final String OPENXML_EXTENSION = "xlsx";

    private final static Logger LOGGER =
            Logger.getLogger(UpdateEmbeddedDoc.class.getName());

    // Here in the contractor we give the path of the word document (docFilePath) that it contains the excel embedded files
    public UpdateEmbeddedDoc(String docFilePath) throws FileNotFoundException,
            IOException {
        this.docFile = new File(docFilePath);
        if (!this.docFile.exists()) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("The Word document " + docFilePath + " does not exist.");
        }
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(this.docFile)) {
            // Open the Word document file and instantiate the XWPFDocument class.
            this.doc = new XWPFDocument(fis);
        }
    }

    public void updateEmbeddedDoc(String ExcelFile1, String ExcelFile2) throws OpenXML4JException, IOException {
        List<PackagePart> embeddedDocs = this.doc.getAllEmbeddedParts();

        //in this example we have two embedded excel files the first one it is in first index 0
        //the second excel file will be on the second index 1 (0 based index)
        PackagePart pPart0 = embeddedDocs.get(0);
        PackagePart pPart1 = embeddedDocs.get(1);
        LOGGER.info("embedded first part : " + embeddedDocs.get(0));
        LOGGER.info("embedded second part : " + embeddedDocs.get(1));

        //Here we are calling copyWorkbook method and give the path of the excel file (ExcelFile1 and ExcelFile2 )
        // that it contains the data that we want to copy to embedded execl files (pPart0 and pPart1 )
        copyWorkbook(ExcelFile1, pPart0);
        copyWorkbook(ExcelFile2, pPart1);


        if (!embeddedDocs.isEmpty()) {
            try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(this.docFile)) {
                this.doc.write(fos);
            }
        }


    }

    public void copyWorkbook(String inputExelFilePath, PackagePart pPart) {
        try {

            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(inputExelFilePath);
            Workbook workbookInput = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            String ext = pPart.getPartName().getExtension();

            if (BINARY_EXTENSION.equals(ext) || OPENXML_EXTENSION.equals(ext)) {
                try (
                        OutputStream os = pPart.getOutputStream()) {
                    //Here we write our workbook (excel file) to the outputStream that refer to excel embedded file
                    workbookInput.write(os);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    LOGGER.severe("Could not update the excel file : " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.severe("Could not update the excel file : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

to test the code :

```
public class VdslmopApplication {
    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(VdslmopApplication.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // here we provide all the path for the files word document file and the two excel files 
        //its better to provide relative path to the files
        String docFilePath = "docfile/docTest.docx";
        String excelFile1Path = "excelFile/excelFile1.xlsx";
        String excelFile2Path = "excelFile/excelFile2.xlsx";

        try {
            UpdateEmbeddedDoc ued = new UpdateEmbeddedDoc(docFilePath);
            ued.updateEmbeddedDoc(excelFile1Path, excelFile2Path);
            logger.info("Doc file has been successfully updated ");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OpenXML4JException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```